# Print line if contains only one string (two files)

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to print a line from file 1 if contains at most one string of file 2.

File 1:

```
key1    value1  value2  value8  value9
key2    value1  value3  value9
key3    value1  value8  value10
```

File 2:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
value5
value6
value7
```

Desired output:

```
key3    value1  value8  value10
```

Thanks, Bernardo

Comment: maybe make use of diff?

Comment: Also what have you tried and your example shows is a little confusing and contradicts what you want I think...

Comment: You say in your question that you want print only lines with one string in of file2, but in you desired output you show everything but only one string of file2

Comment: Only one is OK, line with key3 should be printed entirely

Comment: Are you trying to print the lines that are "OK" or the lines that aren't? Is one value correct or incorrect? If one value is correct and you want the "OK" lines why is the `key3` line supposed to be printed? Because it has only one of the values from file 2 even though it has other values?

Comment: This is still very confusing after the edits.

Comment: Lines that are OK. One value is correct

Comment: One or less is OK, no more.

Comment: @Bernardo but you seem to contradict that with your example. You should make a more clear example

Comment: Done, now more clear?

Comment: no. this still doesnt hold true "I would like to print a line from file 1 if contains at most one string of file 2."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next}
       {
        c=0;
        for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
            if($i in a){c++}
        } 

       } 
       c<=1;' file2 file1
key2    value1
```

#### Explanation

- `NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next}` : while reading the first file (while the line number of the file, FNR, equals the line number of all input, NR), save the first field in the `a` array. Then, skip to the next line. This will run until the 2nd file is reached when the script will continue to the other lines.
- `c=0;` : reset the counter to 0.
- `for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){}` : for every field in the line from the 2nd to the last.
- `if($i in a){c++}` : increment `c` by one if the current field is in `a`, if it was found in the first file.
- `c<=1` : this is `awk` shorthand for `if(c<=1){print}`.

Comment: You can probably simplify this a little by adding `if(c>1){next}` after the `c++` line, removing the `if(c==1)` line and adding `{print}` or `7` or `1` or whatever true value you are most fond of after the closing `}`.

Comment: This is what I would like to do myself, maybe this time is good try to understand well.

Comment: @EtanReisner that sounded very reasonable but, unless I misunderstood, it will also print cases where `c==0` which the OP doesn't want.

Comment: @terdon Fair point though easy enough to resolve. Use `c` as your "true value" since `0` isn't true for awk.

Comment: @EtanReisner ah, sneaky! I can't get it smaller than this though which is no simpler than what I've posted: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next}{c=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($i in a){c++; if(c>1){next}}}{if(c){print}} }' file2 file1`. Using `c;` in the same way as `1;` to print the line does not work on my awk. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Not `{if(c){print}}` just `c`. The default action is to print. So `c` is a pattern of that variable with the default `{print}` action. `if(c)` will also serve in place of `if(c>1)` if you move it before the increment. Also, if you want to drop the short-circuiting of `next` for long lines then you can drop the `if(c>1){next}` block too and just use `c==1` as the final pattern (instead of `c`).

Comment: @EtanReisner yes, I had understood but was doing something silly and couldn't get it to print using the variable alone. Never mind, figured it out and thanks!

Comment: Cases where c==0 are also OK, maybe "c==1||c==0"

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -v '.*value1.*value2.*' input
key2    value1
```

Assuming that `input` file contains

```
key1    value1  value2
key2    value1
```

Comment: This is good for one case, however will he always be using the same files is my question, if not he is in trouble.

Comment: @jgr208 provided the input, this is all that i can guess. If he is in trouble, its his fault

Comment: Yes he is. Wasn't bashing your answer it does work. Just saying the person who asked the question should never assume he will always have the same files and look to make it program as portable as possible.

Comment: Apart from relying on specific input, this will fail in cases where you have `value2  value1`.

Comment: I'm using two files, not only an input file.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
cat file2 | awk '{print "\\b" $1 "\\b"}' | grep -n -o -f - file1 | cut -d: -f1 | uniq -c | awk '$1==1{print $2}' | xargs -r -i -n1 sed -n "{} p" file1
```